# how to programmatically start and stop zookeeper server

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper

I would like to be able to start, stop and configure a zookeeper server in my java program. Is there a way to be able to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute (spawn) new process in java with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` and `Java SE 1.5 ProcessBuilder` there is one more option [apache open source project](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/)

```
String line = "AcroRd32.exe /p /h " + file.getAbsolutePath();
CommandLine cmdLine = CommandLine.parse(line);
DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
int exitValue = executor.execute(cmdLine);
```